# How to get an image from google places api?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, axios, xmlhttprequest, base64

I'm currently stuck on trying to get an image from the Google Places API, in the documentation is stated to get an image you have [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=[imagereference]&key=[yourkey]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=%5Bimagereference%5D&key=%5Byourkey%5D)

This will then redirect you to a URL with the actual image. How do I do this process with axios or fetch as I'm trying to obtain the base 64 image version so that I can use inside my react application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to show the Places API photo in client side applications, you need to use the [Places Photos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos) of the Google Maps JavaScript Places Library.

The code snippet below shows a sample of how I get the photo URL from the `getDetails` result and put it inside my state variables:

```
       const request = {
              placeId: "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
              fields: [
                "name",
                "formatted_address",
                "place_id",
                "geometry",
                "photos"
              ]
            };

            const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
              if (
                status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK &&
                place &&
                place.geometry &&
                place.geometry.location
              ) {
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                });
              }
              this.setState({
                photos: place.photos[0].getUrl(),
                name: place.formatted_address
              });
            });
```

Here is the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/places-photos-knxynn?file=App.js) and to see this work, replace the `YOUR_API_KEY` from the script inside `Map.js` with your API Key.